# How two start two different events at different time?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

```
private ImageView poweredByImage;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    poweredByImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    poweredByImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.powered_by);        
    this.handleAnimation(poweredByImage);

    Handler handler = null;
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
             startActivity(intent);
         }
    }, 3000);
}

public void handleAnimation(View v) {
    v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein));
}
```

}

I navigate from one screen (SplashScreen) to another (HomeScreen), 3 seconds after the first one appears, but before that to happen I want to start the fade-in animation 1 second after it appears and then the transition to new screen to happen.

So how can I do it? What should I use? Any help will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use your handler to post a Runnable responsible of starting the animation after 1000ms? You then post your second Runnable that start your HomeScreen activity after 3000ms like you are actually doing.

Comment: I did it, but is there any better way to do it? Some alternative?